# Objective C , opening a website without opening it in Safari (for server call purposes)

Tags: objective-c, web-services, xcode4.2

I am using objective C and I am trying to load a website without opening it in Safari :

I am using the following function :

```
 NSString *website =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com"];

 NSString *connected = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:website ]encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
```

but when I check in my database I noticed that it does not load the website , when I load it in the browser it does detect it tho , any reasons ?

thanks

Comment: NSString *website =[NSString stringWithFormat:"http://www.website.com"]; You forgot to add "@" NSString *website =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com"];

Comment: edited my question , still the same issues :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use the `NSURLConnection` class to retrieve data from the network.   It will provide a much more useful set of errors, etc.

For simple (but blocking), you can start off with `-sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:`, which retrieves a URL from the network giving you the data (in the return value), the HTTP Response, and an error.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.website.com"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: &response error: &error];
```

If data isn't nil, you've gotten a valid response, otherwise error contains information about the response.   You still need to double-check the `response` in order to make sure you got what you wanted (not a "successful" response that resulted in an error due to the server sending back an error code for HTTP).

In the future, if you need to do a POST command, you can use NSMutableURLRequest and set the type of the request.

Comment: thank you for your post : I encountered the following issues :
after running all this code I noticed that : response is nil ,error has a value in it and data is  nil , any reasons ?

Comment: The error response will contain details on what is wrong.   Check that first.   NSLog( @"%@", error) is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Vlad is right, but your code will also only load one file. When you open that file in a browser like Safari, the browser will recursively load all referenced files and will handle any redirect that is present.

UPDATE

In a browser, using the URL without the file name works. I'm not sure you can do that with stringWithContentsOfURL: or with an NSURLConnection.

If the file name is something like "index.html" or whatever it is, try adding that to your URL. These methods load files, so I am betting that you need to provide a fully defined URL, including the file name.

Comment: I might have not expressed myself properly , I do not want to open it in Safari at all

Comment: So what do you want to do? Load the one file, or recursively load all of them?And did you try Vlad's suggestion?

Comment: I want to load a website without opening it in Safari . and yes I followed Vlad's suggestion