# Unable to Call a webservice

Tags: objective-c, web-services

I am trying to call a webservice but unfortunateley my calls are not recorded and I am not sure why it is doing so ...

here is the code that I am using , maybe I am missing something :

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

all I need to do is to be able to load a web page without having to load it in safari nor in a web view

thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C , opening a website without opening it in Safari (for server call purposes)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726389/objective-c-opening-a-website-without-opening-it-in-safari-for-server-call-pu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service) on how to connect with a webservice in iOS. It's not as simple as making the connection.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:webService];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];    
    if(theConnection) {
        //webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];      
    }else {
        NSLog(@"The Connection is NULL");
    }
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [webData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
}
```